# PAGINATION PROBLEM ON MODELS CREATED WITH ELEMENTOR

Tags: wordpress, pagination, elementor

I'm currently working on a site on which I've created models with elementor's theme builder. After using my template and enabling pagination in a layout on an elementor page, I noticed that pagination doesn't work. When I want to see the other pages it reloads the first page each time.

Please help me to solve this problem please.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is work for me.
Drag HTML widget to your page and paste :
[code](https://gist.github.com/penerbangkode/9faebfdafb8b750077da3fa91f6b38e6)

[Source Discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementor/comments/i8hyw4/post_widget_pagination_issue/)